# Process audio sounds from microphone using Qt

Tags: qt

I am developing a sound processing application using Qt as a front end.
How can I get data samples from the microphone? I tried overriding `qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 len)` in  `QIODevice`, but I was unable to get data samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use QAudioInput class.
see : [QAudioInput Class ref in Qt Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudioinput.html)